# Unhandled process fault due to exceeding maximum characters in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, workflow

I have a visualFlow,
And I am getting an “Unhandled process fault” error, 
When someone enters more than 255 characters in one of my text box's,
I am using the following validation:

```
LEN({!Other_Lan}) > 255
```

But it doesn’t seem to work,
Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation rule should be for <255 rather than >255.  Try it out with a smaller value to get a better understanding of what it is doing. (Assuming you are trying to limit them to under 255 for saving data to a basic text field, otherwise, use a long text field in the Flow)